# Trouble with height of h1 tag, seems to be inheriting from another object

Tags: html, css

I can't really explain my issue so here is an example:

If you inspect the very first `<h1>` tag you'll notice that its height is inheriting from another object. I'd like to fix that...

```css
.wrapper {
 width: 1300px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
}

.feed {
 width: 950px;
 height: 800px;
 border-right: 2px solid #f0f0f0;
}

.videoContainer {
 background-color: #fafafa;
 width: 950px;
 height: 450px;
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
}

#videoTitle {
    margin: 0;
 color: #333;
 font-size: 22px;
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
                <div class="feed">
                    <div class="videoContainer"><iframe width="800" height="450" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8GpDXV9BfLU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
                    <h1 id="videoTitle">Something here</h1>
                    <h1 id="videoTitle">Something lorem ipsum.. To make this text a bit longer than the previous one.</h1>
                    <h1 id="videoTitle">and something short.</h1>
                </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: First you can't assign several id. The id must be unique. Replace it with class instead. Then your problem is unclear. Everything is allright ..

Comment: I would also re-consider the use of `h1` here. There are SEO implication to having multiple `h1` per page and they don't even appear to be section headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `clear: left;` to the `<h1>`. Currently it is taking on the height of `.videoContainer` because of the `float: left;` on it.

Comment: As @zlen said don't use duplicate id's. In fact in general it is usually considered best to avoid id's altogether in your css and just use classes.

Comment: Also make sure you mark this question as answered (big tick next to the up / down arrows) so that other people can see that it has been answered.

Comment: Yes `Id` should not be repeated, but there is still a large amount of debate if it is "usually considered best to avoid id's altogether in your css". There are many valid uses for `ID` admittedly there are more invalid uses.

Comment: @JonP I have yet to meet a developer who recommends using id's over classes in css. Of course it is valid to use id's in your css but there doesn't seem to be any advantages and there is many disadvantages so why would you? I don't want to discuss this here though, I often hang out in the web design room if you want to discuss further: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29074/html-css-webdesign

Answer (score 0):

you want to do a `clear: left;` that means it wont inherit from the class `.videoContainer` anymore.

```
#videoTitle {
  margin: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  clear: left;
}
```